# If I translate French article to English, can google detect it?

Tags: content, translation

I noticed that if I translate content from French into English, CopyScape passes that content.

Can Google detect that the content was translated? CopyScape determined that it is plagiarism free.

I'm using Google translator.

Comment: How are you translating the content?  Are you doing a machine translation or are you using a person that knows both languages well and can write English like a native speaker?

Comment: I'm Using google translator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Google does not view translated content as duplicate, as content in another language is different than if it is appearing in the same language twice.However, it is recommended to have a human translation as Googlebots can tell if the site has been translated using Google Translate and may view it as 'spammy'.

Comment: What if i use bing translator ?

Comment: It doesn't matter what software you use to do the translation, [Google views all automatic translation done without human review or curation as automatically generated](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2721306).  The webmaster guidelines (linked) prohibit placing any automatically generated content  where it can be indexed by Google.